# How do I put a background under a transparent ListView?

Tags: android

right now what I have is just a listview with a custom gradient as the background color. When I have 2 items in my list, the rest of the background beneath it is just all black. I can't set a background image anywhere that would make a background show up. My desired outcome is to have a background image in the back of the entire view where a transparent listview would overlay it. How could this be done? Let me know if you guys need more info/code from my project.

Thanks!

This is my listview in main.xml

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/store_list2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/store_div2"
    android:divider="#000000"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"/>
```

This is the list_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
 android:state_selected="false"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg" />

<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover" />

<item android:state_selected="true"
 android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover" />
</selector>
```

this is my list_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp" >

<!--  Application Icon -->
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/gmg_thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/gmg_list_image"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />

</LinearLayout>

<!-- Title-->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/gmg_title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/gmg_thumbnail"
    android:textColor="#040404"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

 <!-- Rightend Arrow -->
 <ImageView 
    android:contentDescription="@string/right_arrow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/scaled_arrow"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?, your question is not clear..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your desired background on the Parent Layout containing ListView.

```
android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
```

Like this (Assuming RelativeLayout is yout parent layout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" >

   <ListView
    android:id="@+id/store_list2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/store_div2"
    android:divider="#000000"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this property `android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"` to ListView